# Route traffic based on HTTP headers

Tags: routes, load-balancing, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer, system-design

I am designing a scalable micro-service architecture using Kubernetes. The current setup looks like this:

`Client --> Route53 --> ALB(Ingress) --> Application (Running inside EKS cluster)`

This works fairly well with one Application Load Balancer(ALB). Now I want to scale this architecture by creating multiple EKS clusters in the same/different regions. The architecture diagram I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```
                        ________ ALB 1(Ingress) --> Application (Running inside EKS cluster 1)
                       |
Client --> Route53 ----|
                       |________ ALB 2(Ingress) --> Application (Running inside EKS cluster 1)
```

There can be `n` number of such ALBs available. I want to redirect the request from Route53 --> ALB depending on a particular header value. How can I add custom logic to determine the appropriate ALB?

I am free to use some other service instead of Route53 if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 approaches come to mind-

1. Using single ALB and sub-domain(say foo.domain.com)- In order to do a URI-based routing, you would need a reverse proxy like Nginx behind your ALB where you could implement URI-based routing. Something like this -

> Any Domain --> ALB --> Nginx (Clustered/Active-Passive) -->  Application 1 or
> Application 2

2. Using multiple ALBs and sub-domains(say foo.domain.com, bar.domain.com)- Now you can create multiple target groups, 1 corr. to 1 ALB and do a sub-domain based routing. Something like this -

> Domain 1 --> ALB 1 -->  Application 1

> Domain 2 --> ALB 2 -->  Application 2

Comment: In the second approach, we will have total 3 ALB’s right… The first ALB which will route to other two ALB’s based in HTTP header or path based routing, right ?

Comment: no. 2 alb's for 2 domains. the client(app/web) will call correct domain. if you want the client(app/web) to call a single domain, you would have to do something like this- https://shailender-choudhary.medium.com/aws-alb-advanced-request-routing-315d26682ded

Comment: @MukulBansal Approach 1 is best suitable in my case as I want the client to call a single domain. But now I am struggling to route traffic based on HTTP headers using Nginx :(

Comment: could you share your nginx config here if possible so that i can take a look at it

Comment: Thanks for responding @MukulBansal. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I am free to use some other CDN instead of Route53 if required.

**Route53** is **DNS** service not the **CDN**

Yes, you can do the same as mentioned above. You can add the **alias** record to **route53** and also policy keep something like **weighted** so it will do the load balancing too if you are expecting.

Ref doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/real-time-communication-on-aws/cross-region-dns-based-load-balancing-and-failover.html

Ref for **route53** : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/real-time-communication-on-aws/cross-region-dns-based-load-balancing-and-failover.html